# In R shiny, how can I use data that I generated in an observeEvent (button click) outside of that observeEvent?

Tags: r, shiny

Say I do an observeEvent like this where I generate random numbers, and then another to export those numbers to a csv:

```
  observeEvent(input$generateButton, {
    u = runif(input$nNumericInput)
  })
  observeEvent(input$exportButton, {
    write.csv(data.frame(u),"randomNumbers.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  })
```

That's basically what I'm trying to do but I'm generating the numbers in a more complex way that I don't want to repeat for each button because of efficieny.

Comment: hey @heds1, thanks for the comment. It does make sense, however, I'm getting an error: Error in df: could not find function "df". Right when I click the second button

Comment: Hey Marco, I've put some more info in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example. I'm also showing a table of the data that's produced when you update the numericInput. This should save in your working directory. Note that `my_df` is generated with an `eventReactive`, because it should be a reactive value (it should change when we change the numericInput), whereas `write.csv` is called within an `observeEvent`, because it's simply triggered by clicking the button (i.e., it's not creating any reactive object). Hope that helps.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            numericInput(
                inputId = 'num_input',
                label = 'Input',
                value = 5),
            actionButton(
                inputId = 'num_input_button',
                label = 'Generate df'),
            actionButton(
                inputId = 'write_data',
                label = 'Write to csv')
        ),
        fluidRow(
            tableOutput('table')
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    my_df <- eventReactive(input$num_input_button, {
        runif(input$num_input)
    })

    observeEvent(input$write_data, {
        write.csv(my_df(), 'random_numbers.csv')
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        my_df()
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```